# Modal no carga en version movil desde el celular

Tags: bootstrap, wordpress, modal, popup

Estoy cargando un modal de un contador regesivo al iniciar la pagina. El modal funciona bien cuando lo ves desde una navegador de un lapto o escritorio pero si ingreso desde una navegador de mi celular no carga dicho modal.

esta es la pagina: https://piedradeagua.com.ec/

**mi codigo del modal**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal" id="mostrarmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--<div id="countdown"></div>     
    </div>-->
<div class="text-center"><h4 id="ticonta">¡Prepárese! Muy pronto podrá revivir la experiencia Piedra de Agua</h4><div>
<div data-type="countdown" data-id="1988325" class="tickcounter" style="width: 100%; position: relative; padding-bottom: 25%"><a href="//www.tickcounter.com/countdown/1988325/preparese-muy-pronto-podra-revivir-la-experiencia-piedra-de-agua" title="¡Prepárese! Muy pronto podrá revivir la experiencia Piedra de Agua">¡Prepárese! Muy pronto podrá revivir la experiencia Piedra de Agua</a><a href="//www.tickcounter.com/" title="Countdown">Countdown</a></div><script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//www.tickcounter.com/static/js/loader.js"; pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs); }(document, "script", "tickcounter-sdk"));</script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**codigo js donde me ejecuta el modal al iniciar la pagina**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
         $("#mostrarmodal").modal("show");
      });
    </script>
```

**y por ultimo los estilos**

```
.modal-content {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}

h4{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Justo ahora en mi explorador movil funciona!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent varias opciones pero no se me mostraba el modal, entonces la unica solucion fue instalar un plugin de wordpress que se llama pop up marker.